# Indecomposable vector bundles on elliptic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $X$ be a smooth complex projective curve of genus 3,
$E$ an elliptic curve, and $f: X \to E$ a finite map of 
degree 2. Let $L$ be a line bundle on $X$, and $R^0f_*(L)$
its direct image. Question: is $R^0f_*(L)$ indecomposable?

Answer (score 7):

This depends on the choice of $L$. For instance, if $L = \mathcal{O}_X$ then $f_*L \cong \mathcal{O}_E \oplus L_E$, where $\deg(L_E) = -2$.

On the other hand, if $L$ is a general line bundle of degree 1, then $f_*L$ is indecomposable.

If $L = \mathcal{O}(P)$ for some $P \in X$ the pushforward $f_*L$ is decomposable. Indeed, on the one hand, $f_*L$ is a vector bundle of rank 2 and degree $-1$ (this follows from Riemann-Roch), on the other hand, it has a global section. Therefore, it comes in an exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}_E \to f_*L \to M \to 0,
$$
where $M$ is a line bundle of degree $-1$. But
$$
Ext^1(M,\mathcal{O}_E) = H^1(E,M^\vee) = 0
$$
because the degree of $M^\vee$ is 1, hence the sequence splits and 
$$
f_*L \cong \mathcal{O}_E \oplus M.
$$

Comment: As a matter of fact, in my case $L$ has degree one. I can even assume that $L = \mathcal{O}_X(P)$ for a point $P$ on $X$. How do you argue?

Comment: In this case the pushforward is decomposable, see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank's for the explanation. What is your argument if $L$ has degree one and $L$ is general?

Comment: Actually, the question I have in mind is the following: let $P$ be a point on $X$, and let $M$ be a line bundle on $X$ with trivial fourth power.
Let $L=\mathcal{O}_X \otimes M$.
Question: does $R^0f_*(L)$ have a section?
I thought I could use Atiyah's paper to answer this

Comment: You probably mean $L=\mathscr{O}_X(P)\otimes M$. Anyway we have $H^0(f_*L)=H^0(L)$, so your question boils down to whether $H^0(L)=0$; it has nothing to do with vector bundles on $E$, the answer depends on the choice of $P$ and $M$.

Comment: $X$ is hyperelliptic and $P$ is a Weierstrass point.
I have no information on $M$ (except its fourth power is trivial).

Comment: If $M$ is of order 4 *exactly* (not 2), then $H^0(f_*L)=0$.

Comment: I am also interested in the case where $M$ has order 2. How do you argue if $M$ has order 4?

Comment: $H^0(L)$ is nonzero if and only if  $M=\mathscr{O}_X(Q-P)$, with $Q$ also a Weierstrass point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105395/discussion-between-user95246-and-abx).